# what is output type of method when returns result of linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, methods, output

I use Linq query instead of using Sqlserver's view. I want to put it in method .what is my output type? thanks for helping

```
public ???? InsuranceWorkerView()
{
    var InsuranceWorkers =(from ins_insuranceworkers in db.INS_InsuranceWorkers
         join dv in db.DivisionCountry on new { InsWorkerCityID = ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerCityID } equals new { InsWorkerCityID = dv.DivisionID } into divisioncountry_1_join
         from dv in divisioncountry_1_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
         join divisioncountry in db.DivisionCountry on new { InsWorkerStateID = ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerStateID } equals new { InsWorkerStateID = divisioncountry.DivisionID } into divisioncountry_join
         from divisioncountry in divisioncountry_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new 
         {
            ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerID,
            ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerCreateUserID,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerTypeID,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerFirstName,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerLastName,  
            ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerNationalCode,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerMobileNum,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerAddress,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerEmail,
              City = dv.DivisionName,
              State = divisioncountry.DivisionName,
             InsWorkerStateID =(Int32?)ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerStateID,
             InsWorkerCityID = (Int32?)ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerCityID
         }).ToList();

    return InsuranceWorkers;
}
```

Comment: Your are returning Anonymous object

Comment: public obj InsuranceWorkerView(). Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't return [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) from methods:

> You cannot declare a field, a property, an event, or the return type
>   of a method as having an anonymous type. Similarly, you cannot declare
>   a formal parameter of a method, property, constructor, or indexer as
>   having an anonymous type. To pass an anonymous type, or a collection
>   that contains anonymous types, as an argument to a method, you can
>   declare the parameter as type object.

So, either create some specific type for this data and return it:

```
public List<Foo> InsuranceWorkerView()
{
    return (from i in db.INS_InsuranceWorkers
            select new Foo {
                InsWorkerID = i.InsWorkerID,
                InsWorkerCreateUserID = i.InsWorkerCreateUserID
                // etc
            }).ToList();
}
```

Or return `object` (which I find a little useless):

```
public object InsuranceWorkerView()
{
    return (from i in db.INS_InsuranceWorkers
            select new {
                i.InsWorkerID,
                i.InsWorkerCreateUserID
                // etc
            }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the case when dynamic may come in handy.

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> InsuranceWorkerView()
{
    var InsuranceWorkers =(from ins_insuranceworkers in db.INS_InsuranceWorkers
         join dv in db.DivisionCountry on new { InsWorkerCityID = ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerCityID } equals new { InsWorkerCityID = dv.DivisionID } into divisioncountry_1_join
         from dv in divisioncountry_1_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
         join divisioncountry in db.DivisionCountry on new { InsWorkerStateID = ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerStateID } equals new { InsWorkerStateID = divisioncountry.DivisionID } into divisioncountry_join
         from divisioncountry in divisioncountry_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new 
         {
            ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerID,
            ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerCreateUserID,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerTypeID,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerFirstName,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerLastName,  
            ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerNationalCode,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerMobileNum,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerAddress,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerEmail,
              City = dv.DivisionName,
              State = divisioncountry.DivisionName,
             InsWorkerStateID =(Int32?)ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerStateID,
             InsWorkerCityID = (Int32?)ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerCityID
         }).ToList();

    return InsuranceWorkers;
}
```

And then you can use something like:

```
foreach (var worker in InsuranceWorkerView()) {
   var id = (int)worker.InsWorkerID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the new list as IList.

```
public IList InsuranceWorkerView()
{
    var InsuranceWorkers =(from ins_insuranceworkers in db.INS_InsuranceWorkers
         join dv in db.DivisionCountry on new { InsWorkerCityID = ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerCityID } equals new { InsWorkerCityID = dv.DivisionID } into divisioncountry_1_join
         from dv in divisioncountry_1_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
         join divisioncountry in db.DivisionCountry on new { InsWorkerStateID = ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerStateID } equals new { InsWorkerStateID = divisioncountry.DivisionID } into divisioncountry_join
         from divisioncountry in divisioncountry_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new 
         {
            ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerID,
            ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerCreateUserID,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerTypeID,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerFirstName,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerLastName,  
            ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerNationalCode,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerMobileNum,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerAddress,
             ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerEmail,
              City = dv.DivisionName,
              State = divisioncountry.DivisionName,
             InsWorkerStateID =(Int32?)ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerStateID,
             InsWorkerCityID = (Int32?)ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerCityID
         }).ToList();
```

And to access the item

```
   foreach(var item in InsuranceWorkers)
   {
      var a=   item.InsWorkerID; // to access the anonymous items
   }
}
```

Comment: You have found a way to return anonymous objects but you can't access their properties outside the scope of their declaration. You could replace `var` with `dynamic` in the foreach.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify things, I would suggest you to create a kind of a POCO class with the required properties in order to represent the required projection properly instead of selecting it as anonymous type and get involved with annoying dangerous castings.

**Create your POCO class as:**

```
public class InsuranceWorker
{
  public int InsWorkerId {get;set;}
  public int InsWorkerCreateUserId {get;set;}

  //Keep add the necessary properties here...
}
```

**Usage:**

Replace your anonymous selection (`select new`) statement with the *known* type which we've just created above:

```
 select new InsuranceWorker
 {
    InsWorkerId = ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerID,
    InsWorkerCreateUserId = ins_insuranceworkers.InsWorkerCreateUserID,
    //....
 }).ToList();
```

**and return `IList<InsuranceWorker>`:**

```
public IList<InsuranceWorker> InsuranceWorkerView()
{
  ....
}
```